# How do I plot points on a map using D3.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, r, google-maps, d3.js

Ok, before saying that this question is too "opinion based" and voting it down, hear me out. I have a geo visualization project in which I'm trying to plot air crash locations on a world map with a hover/mouse over function. I have a map ready. In fact I have two maps ready, a globe one and a flat one. I also have a CSV file with 5000 observations. They do not have longitudes and latitudes. How would I go about plotting the locations in the CSV onto the map?

I'm not looking for code, I'm asking the community for tutorials and ideas. If you can guide me to someone's blog or description or videos on how to do this, that will be awesome. Again, before down voting as "too broad" or "too opinion based" or as some other thing, please read the question again. If you still think the question isn't properly asked, throw in a comment and I'll edit it. [Globe Map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IRqcw.jpg) and [Flat map with hover function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uWFkc.jpg)

Comment: Perhaps reading and following some D3 tutorials is a good starting point?

Comment: Any specific site you'd recommend? A link could be useful.

Comment: I'd also suggest http://leafletjs.com/

Comment: No, I don't. This is a poor question to ask here. Google searches would give you plenty of results.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking forward to. @Gopala, you'd think I wouldn't have done that before I came here?

Comment: @echonax Thanks! Will check it out.

Comment: "They do not have longitudes and latitudes". What data include the csv for georeferencing?. (Cities, countries, counties, stores, location)

Comment: The CSV has Location(City, Country), Date, Time, Flight Manufacturer, Flight Operator, Deaths, People On Board, Summary, Route and Flight Number.

Comment: At some point you must get the coords (lat, lng) of your cities, and make a replacement on your CSV file or on the fly using an array with (city, lat, lng)

Comment: I got it working now. Yes, I have latitudes and longitudes and I can plot them on a map. It's working now.  Just need to get a hover function done on the dot (plot location). Any idea on that?

Comment: Bind events to the interactives elements. Like so: svg.append("circles").data(data).on("mouseover", function(d) { do something }). .on("mouseout", function(d) { another stuff });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](https://github.com/nuket/google-sheets-geocoding-macro) is a way to geocode your place names to latitudes and longitudes.

More importantly, do you really need D3.js for this? Is this just for practicing? If yes, then [these video tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OnqDeuRW5CI) are a great place to start.

If not, and if you care about displaying information on hover, why not use a simple solution like [CartoDB](https://cartodb.com/)? It will serve your purpose pretty well. You can customize the colors, basemaps, tooltips, fonts and most other things you'd care about in a map.

Comment: Yes, D3.js is a mandatory library. No, this isn't for practice. But CartoDB sounds interesting! Thank you so much! I will look into it. Also, thanks a ton for the video link.